# What configuration influences the interval of a kubelet checking the health of the container runtime

Tags: kubernetes

We are currently testing different kubernetes configurations related to resilience `nodeStatusUpdateFrequency, --node-monitor-grace-period, --leader-elect-lease-duration, etc.`. To test these configurations we employ some automated testing, which has shown us that most of the times kubernetes reacts as expected.

The one test which is not reacting as expected is disabling the container runtime on a worker node (which simulates a container runtime failure).

In this tests it takes longer for the kubelet to recognize that the container runtime has failed than, for example, it takes to recognize a node failure. A node is regarded as `Ready` since the kubelet keeps posting a healthy `nodeStatusUpdate`. We can’t seem to find a configuration for the kubelet which influences how often the kubelet checks the health of the container runtime, is it possible to configure this?

Comment: What kind of test did you run? When container runtime failed the node is marked as `NotReady` and it is marked as  unschedulable.

Comment: We disabled and killed the container runtime. As expected, the node is marked as `NotReady`, but only after around 30 seconds. We can successfully configure the time it takes for a node to be scheduled `NotReady` when the node is powered down (through `nodeStatusUpdateFrequency` and `node-monitor-grace-period`) to be much lower than this 30 seconds. We want to influence the time it takes for a container runtime failure to be recognized to be lowered as well.